# Get dot-product of dataframe with vector, and return dataframe, in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dot-product

I am unable to find the entry on the method `dot()` [in the official documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/api.html). However the method is there and I can use it. Why is this?

On this topic, is there a way compute an element-wise multiplication of every row in a data frame with another vector? (and obtain a `dataframe` back?), i.e. similar to `dot()` but rather than computing the dot product, one computes the element-wise product.

Comment: You could post this as [an issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues). If you checkout the docstring on dot it tells you what it does (if you're using ipython use `df.dot?`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example of how to multiply a DataFrame by a vector:

```
In [60]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.], 'B': np.arange(1., 7.)})

In [61]: vector = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3])

In [62]: df.mul(vector, axis=0)
Out[62]: 
   A   B
0  2   2
1  2   4
2  2   6
3  6  12
4  6  15
5  6  18
```

Comment: Thanks!. Do you know why `dot()` is not part of the official doc?

Comment: There are two `dot` methods in Pandas. `Series.dot` is inherited from `ndarray.dot`, since `Series` is a subclass of NumPy's `ndarray`. You can find the documentation for that [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). As for `DataFrame.dot`, my guess is that they simply haven't gotten around to documenting it. (It's behavior is pretty understandable by peeking at its definition in `pandas/core/frame.py` however.)

Comment: Update: `pandas.Series` is no longer a subclass of `ndarray`, but it still has a [`dot` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.Series.dot.html).

Answer (score 12):

`mul` is doing essentially an outer-product, while `dot` is an inner product.  Let me expand on the accepted answer:

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.], 'B': np.arange(1., 7.)})

In [14]: v1 = np.array([2,2,2,3,3,3])

In [15]: v2 = np.array([2,3])

In [16]: df.shape
Out[16]: (6, 2)

In [17]: v1.shape
Out[17]: (6,)

In [18]: v2.shape
Out[18]: (2,)

In [24]: df.mul(v2)
Out[24]: 
   A   B
0  2   3
1  2   6
2  2   9
3  4  12
4  4  15
5  4  18

In [26]: df.dot(v2)
Out[26]: 
0     5
1     8
2    11
3    16
4    19
5    22
dtype: float64
```

So:

`df.mul` takes matrix of shape (6,2) and vector (6, 1) and returns matrix shape (6,2)

While:

`df.dot` takes matrix of shape (6,2) and vector (2,1) and returns (6,1).

These are not the same operation, they are outer and inner products, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, I found this the most helpful answer here. Better than the pandas doc also.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to say with a degree of accuracy.

Often, a method exists and is undocumented because it's considered internal by the vendor, and may be subject to change.

It could, of course, be a simple oversight by the folks who put together the documentation.

Regarding your second question; I don't really know about that - but it might be better to make a new S/O question for it.
Just scanning the the API, could you do something with the DataFrame's .applymap(function) feature ?