# error in using DataFrame.mul, related to ndarray

Tags: numpy, pandas, error-handling, dataframe

I reference from this article,[Get dot-product of dataframe with vector, and return dataframe, in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753916/dot-products-in-pandas), to use DataFrame.mul.
my problem code is this

```
df.mul(weight)
```

where weight is data type of 'numpy.ndarray' with shape (17L, 1L),and the print result is

```
[[  2.37005330e-07]
 [  2.80515078e-07]
 [  2.80267682e-07]
 [  2.79124521e-07]
 [  2.01799847e-07]
 [  2.71495529e-07]
 [  2.81640566e-07]
 [  2.30099310e-07]
 [  1.95221059e-07]
 [  2.10244387e-07]
 [  2.82483251e-07]
 [  2.29050342e-07]
 [  9.99996381e-01]
 [  8.95340469e-08]
 [  3.90767576e-08]
 [  2.31231511e-07]
 [  2.79852240e-07]]
```

where df is a dataframe object with shape [20208 rows x 17 columns], the print result is like

```
                     12&88    17&123 ....
modified datetime                        
2015-09-07 09:19:00  1.000000  1.000000  ....
2015-09-07 09:30:00  1.000000  1.000000  ....
2015-09-07 09:31:00  1.000000  0.974714  ....
2015-09-07 09:32:00  1.000000  0.978203  ....
2015-09-07 09:33:00  1.000000  0.978203  ....
2015-09-07 09:34:00  1.000000  0.990576  ....
....
```

But when i execute df.mul(weight),it occurs

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 17), indices imply (17, 20208)
```

I tried a simpler array with shape (17L,) and there is no problem to use df.mul.so I wonder if it should change the weight to a ndarray to array, but it is difficult to me. How to change OR would there be a better idea to solve this problem? Thank you so much for help!

---

Here is my original code

```
   weight, means, stds = optimal_portfolio(result_framea.transpose())

   c , b= test.pairs_trade(load_path, sNo_list[0])
   result_frame = pd.DataFrame(index = c.index)
   for i, sNo in enumerate(sNo_list):
        c,b = test.pairs_trade(load_path, sNo)
        result_frame[sNo[0]+'&'+sNo[1]] = c['returns']
   df=result_frame.fillna(method='pad')
```

all over are fine, until the moment after df.mul(weight). Again, thank you!

Comment: Can you try `df.mul(weight, axis=0)` basically it uses the minor axis to align due to broadcasting rules

Comment: I also try axis=1 after axis=0, still the same value error.

Comment: but when I randomly set a new 'weight' like array([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1]), it can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `help(pd.DataFrame.mul)`:

> `mul(self, other, axis='columns', level=None, fill_value=None)` unbound `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` method
>
> Multiplication of `dataframe` and `other`, element-wise (binary operator `mul`).
>
> Equivalent to `dataframe * other`, but with support to substitute a `fill_value` for
>       missing data in one of the inputs.

This suggests that in the simplest case `df.mul` will just perform a numpy-style multiplication of the corresponding arrays. So, you're trying to multiply an array of shape `(20208,17)` with one of shape `(17,1)`. This will not work.

The way [*array broadcasting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) works in numpy is that arrays with certain singular dimensions can be automatically expanded by numpy in order to match them to other, larger arrays in arithmetic operations. The catch is that if one of the arrays have fewer dimensions, then *leading* singleton dimensions are assumed.

So, for example, the following array shapes can be multiplied/added/divided/etc together without problems:

- `(1,17)` and `(20208,17)` because the non-singleton dimensions match
- `(17,)` and `(20208,17)` because the first is implicitly compatible with `(1,17)` (leading singleton dimensions are assumed)
- (5,1,17)`and`(1,20208,17)`(or just`(20208,17)`)

The following can't be broadcast together:

- `(1,16)` and `(20208,17)` because there's dimension mismatch
- `(16,) and`(20208,17)`because the mismatch is there even after implicitly expanding the first one to shape`(1,16)`
- `(17,1)` and `(20208,17)` for now obvious reasons

The problem is that pandas shows the cryptic error message you quoted in your question:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 17), indices imply (17, 20208)

The same looks like this in numpy (try `np.random.rand(17,1)*np.random.rand(20208,17)`):

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (17,1) (20208,17)

This latter error is crystal clear, and would have probably saved you a lot of head-scratching.

The solution is simple: `reshape` your weight array from shape `(17,1)` (a column vector in a 2d array) to shape `(17,)` (a 1d array). This can be broadcast with your larger array. To do this, just call `reshape` with a dimension argument of `-1`, telling numpy to determine the length of the 1d array for you:

```
df.mul(weight.reshape(-1))
```

Note that the resut will be the same `shape` as the data in `df`, but each column will be multiplied by the corresponding element from `weight`.